# Expand ( transform ) some of the hive columns as row (record)

Tags: apache-spark, dataframe, hive, apache-spark-sql, transpose

Is there a efficient way to transform the below hive table with shown target transformation. The column count in the source table is ~ 1500.
Using spark 2.0, source and target as dataframes.

```
(id,   dt ,       source1_ColA, source1_ColB, source2_ColA, source2_ColB)
------------------------------------------------------------

(10,"2018-06-01",   10,             9,          5,          8       )

(20,"2018-06-01",   20,             12,         16,         11      )
```

The columns A,B are transformed as shown below
Target table

```
(id, dt ,   element_name,  source1,  source2 )
---------------------------------------

(10,"2018-06-01",   ColA    ,     10    ,   5       )

(10,"2018-06-01",   ColB    ,      9    ,   8       )

(20,"2018-06-01",   ColA    ,     20    ,   16      )

(20,"2018-06-01",   ColB    ,     12    ,   11      )
```

Comment: Could you please show what you've already tried.

Comment: @LazerBass - For each of the columns (ColA,ColB, ...)   --> 
(1) ColA - Select [id, dt, src1_ColA,src2_colA,..] – transform as dataframe -> [id, dt,data_elmnt='ColA',src1,src2] <-- df1  (2) 

ColB - Select [id,dt,src1_ColB,src2_colB,...] – transform as dataframe -> [id, dt, data_elmnt='ColB',src1,src2] <--- df2 3) 
Result DF = df1 union df2 
Any better way to do this transpose (reverse-pivot?)